# What is meant by 'scalars in modules'?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, modules, scalar-fields

I want to understand better when from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(mathematics)#Scalars_in_modules) they say

> When the requirement that the set of scalars form a field is relaxed so that it need only form a ring [..] In this case the "scalars" may be complicated objects [..]

I was studying the *restriction of scalars* but I really don't understand direct connection between scalars & modules.

1. a set of scalars can be generated directly from modules if set of scalars form a field but only if field is 'relaxed' to form a *ring* ?
2. what does this 'field relaxed' term mean in context of scalar-module relation ?

Comment: When you say "I was studying the _restriction_ of scalars", what is the context (i.e., what course, what textbook)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $V$ is a vector space over a field $K$, the elements of $K$ are usually called scalars, since they can be used to scale a vector $v$ as $\lambda\cdot v$ for $\lambda\in K$. Now take the definition of a vector space and just replace the field $K$ by a ring $R$ (this is what is meant by relaxing the definition). You still want a "scalar multiplication" $R\times V\to V$ so $\lambda\cdot v$ makes sense for $\lambda\in R$ and $v\in V$. Hence your scalars are now elements of $R$. What you get is no longer a vector space but an $R$-module.

Comment: mm..but to replace the field $K$ by a ring $R$ what is the theorem behind to do this formal replacement like *relaxing the definition* ? So scalars are not 'generated' from module but simply change the algebraic structure that contains them. 
Are there any significant implications related to this substitution in the physical context (quantum, string theory *etc*) ? Maybe topologically ?

Comment: There is nothing formal here, you just copy/paste the definition you have for vector spaces, replace "$K$-vector space" by "$R$-module", replace "field" by "ring" and all occurences of $K$ by $R$. This way you get a *new definition*, and since you just weakened some conditions, namely $K$ satisfying only the ring axioms, not the field axioms, you call the new definition a "relaxed" version of the old one.

Comment: Very interesting follow this method, I did not think it was possible, thanks again.